# Emacs open previous revision - Git vs Mercurial

Tags: git, emacs, mercurial

I've just migrated from Mercurial to Git and previously found the emacs `C-x v ~` very useful for opening previous revisions as a new buffer.

In Mercurial it was easy to specify the revision (changeset ID), as this was typically a small integer, e.g. 23 if you wanted the 23rd commit out of, say, 24 total commits.

However, now trying to do this in Git is not so easy. I have to specify a large hash value.

Is there a more user friendly way around this to avoid the otherwise inevitable copy and pasting?

Comment: You only need to enter the first 8 maybe less characters of the sha. Enough for it to be unique.

Comment: possibly i should take the plunge and start using magit

Comment: Does Emacs support [git revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) notation? `@~`, `HEAD~`, `HEAD^`, etc.?

Comment: @phd: Yep; it doesn't try to second-guess or validate the syntax -- it just passes the specified value along to git.  You get completion options for branches and tags, but you can edit the value to be anything you need.